# How to create a single login service to use it in multiple sites ? (similar to Google, Microsoft Account)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, login, oauth2

I want to implement login system where same user account can be used to login in different web applications. How can I achieve this ? I want to make a similar architecture to Google and Microsoft Account where different services can be used using the same account.

I will be working in ASP.NET MVC for this.

Comment: Do you already have some idea of how you could achieve it, or no idea at all?

Comment: I have some idea. I am trying to create a Login server (Site A) with OAuth authentication, which will provide an authorization key to the site(Site B). The authorization key can be used to access the identity of user from site A.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: I am just trying to figure out if it is a good method or not.

Comment: If you want to figure out if it's a good method why not ask if it's a good method?

Comment: Yes, but I am bit unsure about this so.

Comment: You may be looking for [Single Sign-On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).

Answer (score 1):

Using someone else's OAuth service (Google, Microsoft Live, Facebook, Twitter) is a good idea, but implementing your own OAuth server is complex and challenging to say the least.

Have a look here, there's lots of documentation for various scenarios.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer